# How to insert a variable in a query in asp.net c#?

Tags: c#, sql-server

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string email = Request.QueryString["Email"];
    cmd.Connection = cn;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = String.Format("INSERT INTO Job (Industry, JobPosition, ExactAddress, Region, Salary, JobDesc, EmployerID) VALUES ('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}','{5}','Select employerid from employer where email = email')", Industry.SelectedValue.ToString(), TextBox3.Text, TextBox5.Text, Region.SelectedValue.ToString(), TextBox6.Text, TextBox7.Text, email.ToString()); 
    cn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    cn.Close();
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Scripts", "<script>alert('Job Posted!');</script>");
    Response.Redirect("EmployerProfile.aspx");
}
```

Comment: what part is giving you difficulty? what error do you get?

Comment: Im guessing the query is returning all rows - because at the end of the row you have email = email.. so that would be all of them

Comment: Search about how to write parameterized queries instead of trying to concatenate WRONGLY strings together. Too easy to get parsing errors and Sql Injection hacks

Comment: The following should be a good place to start - [Give me parameterized SQL, or give me death](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/), or the classic [Bobby tables](http://bobby-tables.com/). It is probably also a good idea to separate your Data Access Layer from your UI code behind.

Comment: Based on your code it also looks like you are reusing SqlConnection, and SqlCommand objects. There is no benefit to doing this and may cause you to run into complications down the road. It would be better to initiate, use and dispose of a new object each time it is needed.

Comment: Seems like you want the coding done by us. We are not here to give you full codes. It seems like you don't know how to code yourself.

Flagged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method is open to SQL Injection. You should try this:

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string email = Request.QueryString["Email"];
        cmd.Connection = cn;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Job (Industry, JobPosition, ExactAddress, Region, Salary, JobDesc, EmployerID) VALUES (@industry, @jobPosition, @exactAddress, @region, @salary, @jobDesc, (Select employerid from employer where email = @email))";
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@industry", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = Industry.SelectedValue.ToString();
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@jobPosition", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = TextBox3.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@exactAddress", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = TextBox5.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@region", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = Region.SelectedValue.ToString();
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@salary", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = TextBox6.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@jobDesc", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = TextBox7.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@email", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = email.ToString();
        cn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cn.Close();
        cmd.Parameters.Clear();
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Scripts", "<script>alert('Job Posted!');</script>");
        Response.Redirect("EmployerProfile.aspx");
    }
```

Also: Your method didn't work because your inner `SELECT` was filtered like this `email = email`

Comment: Instead of saying "it has error man" say WHAT kind of an error you have.

Comment: it says " Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'EmployerID', table 'JobPosting.dbo.Job'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
The statement has been terminated."

Comment: Seems like your subquery doesn't find anything... No EmployerId.

Comment: I have employerid on my database

Comment: DUDE, the subquery `Select employerid from employer where email = @email` didn't find anything. Check your email you gave, check the subquery. We are not here to write a full code for you. Take my answer, AND TRY. Think YOURSELF!